# std::ctype Derived Class Fails to Compile for char

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ctype

The code below fails to compile with: `override did not override any base class methods` & `do_is is not a member of ctype`.

It works fine for `wchar_t`.

Tested on VC++ 2022, default settings. **[EDIT]** I got the same result for online GCC. It looks like it is a feature, but why?

```
#include <locale>

struct fail_t : std::ctype<char> // works for wchar_t
{
  bool do_is(mask m, char_type c) const override
  {
    return ctype::do_is(m, c);
  }
};

int main()
{
  // nop
}
```

Comment: Works also for `int8_t` and `uint8_t` (and `std::byte`). Thinking ...

Comment: ... also works (VS 2019/MSVS or clang-cl) for `unsigned char` and `signed char`. Seems like  `std::ctype<char>` has a very special specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not a *complete* answer, but the [cppreference site page for the `std::ctype<char>` specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char)<sup>1</sup> does *briefly* explain (bolding mine):

> This specialization of std::ctype encapsulates character
> classification features for type char. Unlike general-purpose
> std::ctype, ***which uses virtual functions***, this specialization
> uses table lookup to classify characters (which is generally faster).

Note also, on that page, that there is no `do_is()` member function (inherited or otherwise).

As for the "but why" part of your question: I guess the last (parenthesised) phrase covers that: *which is generally faster*.

---

<sup>1</sup> I appreciate that cppreference does *not* represent any official C++ Standard; however, it is generally very reliable and the language used is often rather more understandable than that in those Standard documents.

---

Looking through [this C++17 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), there is another possible answer to the "but why" question:

> **25.4.1.3 ctype specializations [facet.ctype.special]**
> <sup>1</sup>     A specialization `ctype<char>` is provided so that the member functions on type `char` can be implemented inline.